# Use pointer calculation LONG_LONG_MAX as 2^x

Tags: c++

This is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;

long long (*p)(long long*, long long*) = 0;

long long log(long long* a, long long* b){
    if (*a == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (*a == 1) {
        return *b;
    }
    else if (*b == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (*b == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    *b /= *a;
    return (*p)(a, b) + 1;
}

int main()
{
    long long a = 2;
    long long b = LONG_LONG_MAX;
    p = &log;
    cout << (*p)(&a, &b) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In section:

```
*b /= *a;
return (*p)(a, b) + 1;
```

I want use only one statement instead of two statement.
So, can I do it? If can do it, pls guide me to change it. Thanks everyone!

Comment: What and why do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @this be cause if I don't use pointer I will can do this with one statement. I think pointer verry verry so strong. So I think pointer can do this better.

Comment: It's a little bit confuse.. what do you want? Join these sentences in a unique one? `return (*p)(a, (&(*b /= *a)) ) + 1;`

Comment: @DavidIsla It true, I don't know why my first time I try it, it can't work. Maybe this time I fail something. Thank you! So how to close this topic? Or it don't need close?

Comment: @NguyễnVănDũng if you have an right answer, mark your question as solved. Byes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible answer...

```
return (*p)(a, (&(*b /= *a)) ) + 1;
```

Good luck!